# How to get id after insert statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have such procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreateNativeUser;

delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateNativeUser (p_email varchar(100), p_pass varchar(32))
BEGIN

 insert into users(email) values (p_email);
 insert into user_logins_native() values(???, p_email, p_pass);
 commit;

END $$

delimiter ;
```

and I need some way to get user_id because user_logins_native has a foreign key on user_id column of users table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) function:

```
insert into users(email) values (p_email);
insert into user_logins_native() values(LAST_INSERT_ID(), p_email, p_pass);
```